# socket.io - optmize the traffic, by sending less characters

Tags: javascript, object, socket.io

I have no experiences with server client communication. I want to send objects to the server and broadcast them to all connected clients. I'm wondering if the connection would speed up a lot , if I reduced the sent characters like in b). What can I do to optimize the communication?

a) object box:

```
var box = { width:404, height: 808, featureA: 7897, featureB: 123123, .... }
```

b) object box:

```
var box = { w:404, h: 808, A: 7897, B: 123123, .... }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going in right direction. Its ok to reduce the characters in the object box, also make sure your gzip compression is enabled on your webserver and connected client supports it.

[HTTP Compression - WIkipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression)